# Question related to Azure Domain Services and on-premise domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, domainservices

I have an on-premise domain called "mydomain.com".  I'm wanting to extend this domain to Azure via active directory domain services.  When setting the ADDS in azure, should I use a different domain name such as "azure.mydomain.com" or use the same one as my on-premise "mydomain.com"?

Also, does this configuration require a VPN connection via the gateway or can on-premise domains be extended to Azure over the public internet?

Another question relates to if the free Azure AD is needed for this type of deployment or do you have to use Azure Domain Services in addition to the free  Azure AD provided by the tenent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an on-premise domain called "mydomain.com". I'm wanting to
>   extend this domain to Azure via active directory domain services. When
>   setting the ADDS in azure, should I use a different domain name such
>   as "azure.mydomain.com" or use the same one as my on-premise
>   "mydomain.com"?

[Azure AD Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview) provides managed domain services seamlessly regardless of whether your Azure AD tenant is cloud-only or synced with your on-premises Active Directory.

For the [domain name in AADDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started), you have many choices:

- Built-in domain name: By default, the wizard specifies the default/built-in domain name of the directory (with a .onmicrosoft.com suffix) for you.
- Custom domain names: You can also type in a custom domain name.
- Non-routable domain suffixes: We generally recommend avoiding a non-routable domain name suffix.
- Domain prefix restrictions: The prefix of your specified domain name (for example, contoso100 in the contoso100.com domain name) must contain 15 or fewer characters.
- Network name conflicts: Ensure that the DNS domain name you have chosen for the managed domain does not already exist in the virtual network.

If you just want to extend your on-premise domain to the Azure, you don't need to use AADDS to make this, you could just use Azure AD Connect to sync your on-premise domain to the Azure. Because if you want to use AADDS, you also need to sync the on-premise to the azure.

> Also, does this configuration require a VPN connection via the gateway
>   or can on-premise domains be extended to Azure over the public
>   internet?

The process of configuration doesn't require a VPN connection, it just uses the Azure AD Connect to do the synchronization.
[image]

> Another question relates to if the free Azure AD is needed for this
>   type of deployment or do you have to use Azure Domain Services in
>   addition to the free Azure AD provided by the tenent?

The AADDS needs a subscription when you configure it, there is no requirement about the AAD.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  For the first question, I read those points about the DNS guidelines, but I don't think that answers my question.  We will have a custom domain loaded in AAD for "mydomain.com".  When configuring Azure Domain Services, it asks you to provide a domain name.  Should I use the same domain name as my on-premise "mydomain.com" or use a different one "azure.mydomain.com"?

Comment: It's up to you, you can use the on-premise domain name or you can also type in a custom domain name.

Comment: So you don't foresee any issues with using the same domain name as the on premise domain?  If a client in the on-premise domain ping "mydomain.com", wouldn't that actually have two IP addresses (the IP of the local on-premise domain and the IP of the azure domain)?

Comment: If you already verified it in AAD, you can use the same on-premise domain name, and there will be not a conflict about the domain IP. If not yet, you need to custom a new.

Comment: Azure AD sign-in configuration indicates that the domain I'm trying to sync "mydomain.local" has no matching Azure AD Domain.  So does this mean that I have to have a custom domain name called "mydomain.local"?  If so, how would that ever be verified?

Comment: If you want to sync your local domain to the Azure AD, you need to verify your domain, which means the verified domain is registered in public. Because the Azure AD is in public, so you need to register a domain in public, and then you can verify it with Azure AD. After verified, you should add this domain to your local DNS, then when you syncing, the Azure AD can mactch your local domain.

Answer (score 2):

The following link from Microsoft docs highlights under "Network name conflicts" section that same domain name as on-prem domain name should NOT be used as it would cause conflict;

For more details follow the MS doc link below;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance